# Return Unique Records for Field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

We have an access database create a csv list in an access table for each userid that logs into a computer.  The problem is that if a userid logs in multiple times on one computer, than the userid is duplicated.

SO let's say this is what the table structure looks like

```
computer     DailyUsers
ABC-123      ml12, rs12, ml12, ml12, ee13
DEF-456      zx44, aa33, zx44
```

And this is what I want a query to return

```
Computer     DailyUsers
ABC-123      ml12, rs12, ee13
DEF-456      zx44, aa33
```

I tried using both `Group By` and `Distinct` but that looks on a row by row basis, not a field basis

How can this  be achieved in Access 2013?

Comment: This problem would be best solved by fixing the format of the original table. Do you have control over that table's structure?

Comment: @YowE3K - we are working to remedy the structure of the original table - but need a way in access to parse out the data that is already "garbage" in the table.

Comment: What are you doing with the query results?  (If you didn't need it done in the query itself, it would be a relatively simple exercise in VBA to take the query results, split each record on `,`, remove any duplicates, and join the remaining items back together, before doing whatever else you are doing with the data.)

Comment: @YowE3K - doing such in VBA is an option.  Even if create a table of distinct results then update the original table.  We just need the data updated to only house unique values in the userid field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom function in VBA to return only the unique users.

Add this in a VBA module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function DistinctOnly(txt As String)

    Dim arr, v, rv As String
    Dim d As Object

    arr = Split(txt, ",")
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each v In arr
            d(Trim(v)) = 1
        Next v
        rv = Join(d.keys, ",")
    Else
        rv = txt
    End If

    DistinctOnly = rv
End Function
```

Usage:

```
SELECT Table1.[ID], Table1.[Users], DistinctOnly(Table1.[Users]) as UsersX
FROM Table1;
```

Input data and query results:

[image]

Comment: Works exactly as needed!  Thank you so much for the valuable insight and syntax!  Wish I could upvote twice!

Comment: @IcyPopTarts I'll add the extra +1 for you ;)